# Biblatex preformatted citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I have a large number of preformatted citations that I would like to insert into my bibliography. I also have some citations in the biblatex database format. How would I go about using these preformatted citations **and** the biblatex citations so that when I call `\printbibliography`, both types are mixed together in alphabetical order?

Comment: I think that it is actually easier to just include the preformatted citations in your database.

Comment: I think @Dr.ManuelKuehner is right. You can use the `@misc` entry type and even put them in a different bib file which can be added with another `\addbibresource`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner How exactly would I do that?

Comment: Just add the text after the bibliography.

Comment: The question is very unclear.  Have you read an introduction to LaTeX? [Bibliographies with biblatex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you have some citations in `thebibiography` that you want to insert into your 'normal' `biblatex` bibliography? You can't currently do that since `thebibliography` and `biblatex` are fundamentally incompatible. What is the use case you are thinking about?

Comment: I have a large quantity of preformatted citations. I also have a bunch of citations in the biblatex database format. When I call \printbibliography, I would like both types of citations to appear together in alphabetical order.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Biblatex/Biber uses the .bib entries to do the sorting. If you just wanted to add them at the beginning or end, that would be different. But to sort them seems to me a rather different problem: the system is designed to work with database entries (e.g. `.bib`). @moewe ?

Comment: I am assuming that `preformatted citations` means bibliography entries. Citations are the things in the text referring to sources (usually to things in the bibliography or list of references). Don't you need to refer to sources in the body of your document? For that, you need them to have keys you can use to reference the particular sources. (If preformatted means `thebibliography`, you would have the keys. But I'm not clear if that's what you mean or not.)

Comment: Yes, I mean the bibliography entries. It wouldn't be too hard to add keys and manually create inline citations, but it would be a long process to create the biblatex database

Comment: There is text2bib (http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/) that allows you to convert text to a `.bib` file. It might require some manual tweaking, but should be able to convert your 'preformatted' entries to a `.bib` file. As I said there is no way you can somehow 'fuse' your preformatted entries and `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography` into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` and BibTeX are incompatible with 'prefomatted citations'/`\bibitem`. That is because they need to take over full control over the bibliography and how entries are presented there.

You should try and move your already preformatted citations to a `.bib` file, this will be much more convenient for you in the long run. You will be able to use the citations together with different styles and sorting can be taken care of by Biber/BibTeX.

It might be tedious to do this 'by hand', so you could try the text2bib tool (http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/). Depending on the format of your input (your preformatted data) the output can be very good. You should check the resulting `.bib` file thoroughly manually, though.

Another way, and not recommended here, is to 'fake' entries in the bibliography and stuff all the text of one preformatted citation into one field. The [`notes2bib` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) can already do this, but if you need more than the package provides, you may have to steal its idea and expand on it.